# Removing the last character from a string using substr() is not working

Tags: php, html, templates, gmail, substr

I am trying to get the HTML template from the GMAIL original email view, the problem is that gmail adds an `=` character to the end of each line.

I used a `foreach` loop to iterate through the lines and remove the "=" character, but it is still not working at all.

I also have an `if` statement to validate the existence of the character.

## Example GMAIL original view lines:

```
    body[dir=3Drtl] .directional_text_wrapper { direction: rtl; unicode-bid=
i: embed; }

  </style>
</head>
<body lang=3D"en-us" style=3D"width:100%!important;margin:0;padding:0">
  <div style=3D"padding:10px;line-height:18px;font-family:&#39;Lucida Grand=
e&#39;,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#444444">
```

## Code:

```
<?php

$original_email=file("original.html");
foreach ($original_email as   $line) 
 {
    $sbstr=substr($line,-2,1);
    if( $sbstr == "="){
        echo $substr;
    }

 }


?>
```

### UPDATE

I have tried using the `rtrim()` function with no luck.

## The updated code:

```
<?php

    $original_email=file("original.html");
    foreach ($original_email as   $line) 
     {
        /*
        $sbstr=substr($line,-2,1);
        if( $sbstr == "="){
            echo $substr;
        }
        */
        rtrim($line,"=");

     }


    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you need `quoted_printable_decode`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860243/remove-n-from-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the "3D" added in each line, and made a loop that cuts the end of the line and checks if it's equal to `"="` or not, if yes, it deleted it using `substr`.

```
<?php

$original_email=file("original.html");
foreach ($original_email as   $line) 
 {
$line=str_replace("3D","",$line);
if($sbstr=substr($line,-2,1) == "=")
{
$ln=substr($line,0,strlen($line)-2);
    echo htmlentities($ln)."<br>";
}
}


?>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, posting code-only answers is discouraged. It's best to explain what the problem was, and what you have done to solve it.

Comment: I have edited it just now, to clarify what i've exactly done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

> rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

Use the following syntax to remove `=` at the end of the line

```
$line = rtrim($line, "=");
```

Comment: Still not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

using rtim function

```
rtrim ( $sbstr,"=")
```

Comment: Still not doing anything

Comment: use str_replace("=","",$line); if you want to remove ALL  the '=' char

Comment: No , some "=" are needed like in ' `style=` '

Answer (score 1):

Try to trim your string first for whitespace using trim and then rtrim the '=' character.

```
$line = trim($line);
$line = rtrim($line,'=');
```